# Python on raspberry pi with proxy

Tags: python

I can config my Pi3 to connect to internet via proxy settings
but I can not connect my python script to internet with socket lib
Return result always fail

Is there any lib can support this ?

Note: I tried to use pip with --proxy and it can connect & download.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific reason to use the low level socket library, I'd recommend using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library when retrieving data (text or binary) over HTTP.

This library supports proxies as shown [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies).

Answer (score 0):

Shreyas has the best answer, but if you don't want to make code modifications and your proxy is of the HTTP variety (this will not work with a SOCKS proxy) you can configure Python to use it via the environment as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_server#Environment_variables).

```
export http_proxy=http://[domain/IP]:[port]/
./your_script.py
```